# BizTalk ESB Toolkit Dynamic Routing from within Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.0

I'm trying to perform dynamic itinerary routing from within an orchestration by invoking a receive pipeline, much like the provided ItinerarySelectReceiveXml reveive port, to resolve the itinerary for a given message and send it to a direct bound port for ESB routing.  The setup is similar to the ComposedMessageProcessor BizTalk sample.

My receive pipeline is exactly like ItinerarySelectReceiveXml, as far as I can see, except on the ESB Itinerary Select pipeline component (in the ResolveParty stage) I've hardcoded the connection string and ItineraryFactName (e.g. BRI:\policy=MyResolveItineraryRule;useMsg=true;recognizeMessageFormat=true; and Resolver.Itinerary) so that I don't have to do tricks with loopback adapters and incur extra messagebox visits.

The code to invoke the receive pipeline from an expression shape is like this:

// The first message I want to route is just a node on my incoming message

```
strXPath = "/*[local-name()='BeginConversationMessage' and namespace-uri()='http://MyCompany.BeginConversationMessage.v001']/*[local-name()='BeginConversationMessage' and namespace-uri()='http://MyCompany.BeginConversationMessage.v001']";
BeginConversationMessage = xpath(InboundMsg, strXPath);
RcvPipeOutput = Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.XLANGPipelineManager.ExecuteReceivePipeline(typeof(MyCompany.Itinerary_GenericSelector), BeginConversationMessage);
```

This goes fairly well, I can see that the correct Itinerary for the message type is being resolved using SQL Profiler, and I know the itinerary is good because I use it for this message type with a generic itinerary on-ramp.

But I'm getting an exception from the Microsoft.Practices.ESB.PipelineComponents.Dispatcher which I have right after the Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.PipelineComponents.ItinerarySelector (in the resolve party stage)

The docs state that the ESB Itinerary Selector Pipeline Component should set the Microsoft BizTalk Server segment of the itinerary using the following properties: correlationToken, reqRespTransmitPipelineID, interchangeId, receiveInstanceId, epmRRCorrelationToken.

The exception looks like this:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: interchangeId

Source: Microsoft.Practices.ESB.PipelineComponents.Dispatcher

Method: Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage)

Error Source: Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1

Error TargetSite: System.Object[] GetItineraryDataForBAM(Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1.Itinerary, Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.IItineraryStep, System.String)

Error StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1.BAMItineraryProcess.GetItineraryDataForBAM(Itinerary itinerary, IItineraryStep step, String interchangeId)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1.BAMItineraryProcess.SubmitToBAM(Itinerary itinerary, IItineraryStep step, IPipelineContext context, IBaseMessage msg)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1.ItineraryV1.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__8()
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1.ItineraryV1.AdvanceByOrder(ItineraryMessageDirection messageDirection, String serviceInstanceId, IItineraryStep step, Action submitToBam, Boolean advanceStep)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1.ItineraryV1.Advance(IBaseMessage message, IPipelineContext context, IItineraryStep step, Boolean advanceStep)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.OM.V1.ItineraryV1.Advance(IBaseMessage message, IPipelineContext context, IItineraryStep step)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ESB.PipelineComponents.Dispatcher.Execute(IPipelineContext context, IBaseMessage msg)

Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. I've also posted this question to the ESB Toolkit Form here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/biztalkesb/thread/28c5befe-4c7f-4dc1-a5e7-8fe5b3ec1c75

Answer (score 1):

First, I think the key is to preserve the context of the original message. When receiving a message from the pipeline, you need to use the following syntax in a construct shape, in order to restore the context:

```
PipelineMessage = null;

RcvPipeOutput = Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.XLANGPipelineManager.ExecuteReceivePipeline(
    typeof(MyCompany.Itinerary_GenericSelector), BeginConversationMessage);

RcvPipeOutput.MoveNext();
RcvPipeOutput.GetCurrent(PipelineMessage);
PipelineMessage(*) = BeginConversationMessage(*)
```

In fact, the [context of the message needs to be preserved at all times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999139/how-to-resolve-a-transformation-service-with-bre-that-occurs-after-an-orchestrati) during intermediate message contruction in the orchestration. Also, it is important you promote the right context properties before leaving the orchestration.

This can be done by Initializing a correlation on the last send shape in the orchestration. Make sure the correlation includes the correct properties, including the ones mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm off BizTalk and ESB stuff for the mean time so I can't test your solution, but thanks for the response.